# Mostrar la cantidad de divs que se encuentran dentro de otro (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero mostrar la cantidad de divs que han sido agregados dentro del div con la id **caja** también quisiera saber cómo agregar los `div` con botones, ya que los que se muestran aquí se agregan dando click sobre ellos.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#productos').on('click', '.producto', function() {
  
    var e = $(this).clone();
    var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

    if ($("#caja").find("."+identificador).length) {
      alert("Ya fue añadido");
    } else {
      jQuery(e).appendTo('#caja');
    } 
  });
    
  jQuery('#caja').on('click', '.producto', function() {
    jQuery(this).remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="productos" style="background: #ddd; width: 50%;">
  <div class="producto 1" iden="1">producto 1</div>
  <div class="producto 2" iden="2">producto 2</div>
  <div class="producto 3" iden="3">producto 3</div>
</div>
      
<div id="caja" style='background: #000; color: #fff; width: 50%;'></div>

<!-- quiero que la cantidad se muestre dentro de esta etiqueta -->
<span id='quanty'></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quiere obtener el total de div's en su contenedor, sería suficiente con obtener el `length` de la colección de elementos que retorna el selector de `JQuery`, para su ejemplo el selector será, todos los elementos con la clase producto `'.producto'`

Sí desea añadir datos a sus elementos, lo ideal sería [utilizar atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos), *(en Jquery el valor se obtiene con .data('identificador') , hará referencia a data-identificador="algunvalor" )*

```
$("#caja").find('.producto').length
```

**Ejm**

```js
$(function () {
  $('#productos').on('click','.producto',function() {
    var e = $(this).clone();
    var identificador = $(this).data("identificador");
    if($("#caja").find("."+identificador).length){
      alert("Ya fue añadido");
    }else{
      $(e).appendTo('#caja');
    } 
    $('#quanty').text("Actualmente hay " + $("#caja").find('.producto').length + " DIV's");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="productos" style='background: #ddd; width: 50%;'>
  <div class="producto 1" data-identificador="1">producto 1</div>
  <div class="producto 2" data-identificador="2">producto 2</div>
  <div class="producto 3" data-identificador="3">producto 3</div>
</div>
<div id="caja" style='background: #000; color: #fff; width: 50%;'></div>


<!-- quiero que la cantidad se muestre dentro de esta etiqueta -->
<span id='quanty'></span>
```

Sí desea tener botones independientes para agregar los div's , puede cambiar el listener para que tenga como elemento padre el `document` , posteriormente utilizando los atributos data , obtener el elemento para añadir. *(código explicado)*

```js
$(function () {
 //escuchamos el evento click del botón con la clase btnappend
 // estos botones tendrán un atributo data div que hará referencia al
 //data-identificador para obtener el elemento
 $(document).on('click','.btnappend',function() {
  var identificador = $(this).data('div');
  //cuidado si no seleccione su div productos, puede tener comportamiento
  // no deseado, añadiendo más de 1 elemento por click ;)
  var e = $(`#productos [data-identificador='${identificador}']`).clone();
  $(e).appendTo('#caja');
  $('#quanty').text("Actualmente hay " + $("#caja").find('.producto').length + " DIV's");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="productos" style='background: #ddd; width: 50%;'>
  <div class="producto 1" data-identificador="1">producto 1</div>
  <div class="producto 2" data-identificador="2">producto 2</div>
  <div class="producto 3" data-identificador="3">producto 3</div>
</div>
<button class="btnappend" data-div="1">Agregar P1</button>
<button class="btnappend" data-div="2">Agregar P2</button>
<button class="btnappend" data-div="3">Agregar P3</button>

<div id="caja" style='background: #000; color: #fff; width: 50%;'></div>


<!-- quiero que la cantidad se muestre dentro de esta etiqueta -->
<span id='quanty'></span>
```

Comment: Gracias. quisiera saber cómo agregarlos pero con su boton único para cada div y no tener que dar click sobre ellos.

Comment: @Header90 he actualizado mi respuesta para ese detalle **bonus** , aunque la pregunta principal fue respondida con mi respuesta inicial, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como seria:

```js
let box = document.getElementById('caja');
let totalDiv = document.getElementById('total_cajitas');


document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // creamos el div con valor cajita
  let iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  // asignamos clase cajita para poder discriminarlo
  iDiv.className = 'cajita';
  // Agregamos contenido a su html
  iDiv.innerHTML = 'cajita';
  // Agregamos el valor del hijo a caja
  box.appendChild(iDiv)
  // obtenemos la cantidad de elementos dentro de caja
  totalDiv.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#caja .cajita').length;

})


document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // obtenemos la cantidad de elementos dentro de caja
  total = document.querySelectorAll('#caja .cajita').length;
  // Asignamos el valor total de elementos
  totalDiv.innerHTML = total;
  // Validamos que la cantidad no sea negativa
  if (total == 0) return;  
  // quitamos el ultimo hijo
  box.removeChild(box.lastChild)

})
```

```html
<button id='add'>Agregar</button>
<button id='remove'>Quitar</button>

<div id='total_cajitas'>0</div>
<div id='caja'></div>
```